# Распознать объекты на картинке

Tags: java

Подскажите литературу(русскую) или пример программы на Java для распознавания образов. А точнее нужно распознать квадрат, треугольник, круг на фотографии.

Answer (score 3):

Вам поможет преобразование Хафа. Оно позволяет найти на изображении любую кривую, которую вы сможете описать аналитически. Вот несколько ссылок:

- [Статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141438/) - описывает принципы преобразования. Примеры на C#, но вы, думаю, разберётесь
- [Демонстрация принципа работы](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~iocchi/slides/icra2001/java/hough.html) - не слишком наглядно, но это лучшее, что я смог найти
- [Javavis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javavis/) - библиотека для программ компьютерного зрения на Java. Помимо всего прочего там реализовано преобразование Хафа

Comment: @Mr-Al: в качестве "спасибо" на этом сайте нажимают на зелёную кнопку слева от ответа. Если ответ подходит, под ним есть птичка, чтобы принять его. 0% принятых ответов из 22-х вопросов -- это плохой сигнал.